# mongo shell, how do I direct queries to the secondary

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm very new to mongo and I'd like to direct some queries to the secondaries from the mongo shell.

I've read the docs which say to set the read preference.

Specifically

> In the mongo shell, the readPref() cursor method provides access to
>   read preferences.

I've read the docs on the readPref cursor method (here if you're interested: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.readPref/#cursor.readPref) however I can't make it work.

```
mongos> cursor.readPref(secondary);
2015-10-15T10:03:47.480+0000 E QUERY    ReferenceError: cursor is not defined
    at (shell):1:1

readPref(secondary);
2015-10-15T10:04:16.224+0000 E QUERY    ReferenceError: secondary is not defined
    at (shell):1:10

mongos> readPref('secondary');
2015-10-15T10:04:37.848+0000 E QUERY    ReferenceError: readPref is not defined
    at (shell):1:1
```

I've tried every combination of things I can think of, but always get a ReferenceError.

What am I missing / not understanding?

Comment: You are reading the wrong manual page, which is about how to set the preference on a returned "cursor". This is the [correct one](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/) for a global setting that you seem to want.

Comment: Hey thanks! The doc here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/ points to that location.  I've sent them a note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within `mongosh`:

```
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')
```

Reference:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/#specify-read-preference-mode

Comment: Please provide the information that solved the problem in your answer. Links might outdate or change and therfor not work in future. They are great for reference but should not be the main answer.